# Google Cloud Vision API on PHP AppEngine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-vision

I have been using the Google Cloud Vision api with a php app hosted on a private VPS for a while without issue.  I'm migrating the app to Google AppEngine and am now running into issues.

I'm using a CURL post to the API, but it's failing on AppEngine.  I have billing enabled and other curl requests work without issue.  Someone mentioned that calls to googleapis.com won't work on AppEngine, that I need to access the API differently.  I'm not able to find any resources online to confirm that.

Below is my code, CURL error #7 is returned, failed to connect to host.

```
$request_json = '{
            "requests": [
                {
                  "image": {
                    "source": {
                        "gcsImageUri":"gs://bucketname/image.jpg"
                    }
                  },
                  "features": [
                      {
                        "type": "LABEL_DETECTION",
                        "maxResults": 200
                      }
                  ]
                }
            ]
        }';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key='.GOOGLE_CLOUD_VISION_KEY);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request_json);
$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if ($status != 200) {
    die("Error: $status, response $json_response, curl_error " . curl_error($curl) . ', curl_errno ' . curl_errno($curl));
}
curl_close($curl);
echo '<pre>';
echo $json_response;
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switch my code to use URLFetch (file_get_contents) instead of CURL.  Working great so far.  I'm still unsure why CURL didn't work.

Comment: Because you can't use cURL to connect to google owned sites. (it's a restriction of the remote socket API)

Answer (score 0):

The curl request to a Google API fails in PHP because curl uses the Sockets API and Google IPs are blocked with sockets.  This restriction is documented in [**Limitations and restrictions**](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/sockets/#limitations_and_restrictions):

> Private, broadcast, multicast, and Google IP ranges are blocked

---

To send the `POST` request you describe, you can use PHP's stream handlers, providing the necessary context to send the data along.  I've adapted the example shown in [**Issuing HTTP(S) Requests**](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/issue-requests#issuing_an_http_request) to suit your request:

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->

$url = 'https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate';
$url .= '?key=' . GOOGLE_CLOUD_VISION_KEY;

$data = [
    [
        'image' => [
            'source' => [
                'gcsImageUri' => 'gs://bucketname/image.jpg'
            ]
         ],
         'features' => [
             [
                 'type' => 'LABEL_DETECTION',
                 'maxResults' => 200
             ]
         ]
    ]
];

$headers = "accept: */*\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\n";

$context = [
    'http' => [
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header' => $headers,
        'content' => json_encode($data),
    ]
];
$context = stream_context_create($context);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

I also recommend reading [**Asserting identity to Google APIs**](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/appidentity/#asserting_identity_to_google_apis) should you decide to use means of authentication other than an API key like OAuth.

Comment: This code is not working.Any Idea why ?
Warning: file_get_contents(https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=*****************): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0

Comment: Is there any more verbose logging available?  What `error_reporting()` level have you provided?  Can you test sending a `POST` request to any other endpoint this way?  Though the message is terse, it does suggest that no connection is being made at all, let alone turned down.  If this is the case, the issue could be the requesting function and not the **Vision API** server.